# TypeError: a float is required in sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher

Tags: python, hash, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm using sklearn version 0.16.1. It seems that FeatureHasher doesn't support strings (as DictVectorizer does). 
For example:

```
values = [
          {'city': 'Dubai', 'temperature': 33.},
          {'city': 'London', 'temperature': 12.},
          {'city': 'San Fransisco', 'temperature': 18.}
          ]

print("Starting FeatureHasher ...")
hasher = FeatureHasher(n_features=2)
X = hasher.transform(values).toarray()
print X
```

But the following error is received:

```
    _hashing.transform(raw_X, self.n_features, self.dtype)
  File "_hashing.pyx", line 46, in sklearn.feature_extraction._hashing.transform (sklearn\feature_extraction\_hashing.c:1762)
TypeError: a float is required
```

I can't use [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer) since my dataset is very big and the features are with high cardinality so I get a MemoryError. 
Any suggestions?

### Update (October 2016):

As NirIzr commented, this is now supported, as sklearn dev team addressed this issue in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/6173

FeatureHasher should properly handle string dictionary values as of version 0.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is a known sklearn issue:** 
FeatureHasher does not currently support string values for its dict input format

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4878

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for non-numeric features is to transform the keys yourself similar to how `DictVectorizer` does.

```
values = [
      {'city_Dubai':1., 'temperature': 33.},
      {'city_London':1., 'temperature': 12.},
      {'city_San Fransisco':1., 'temperature': 18.}
      ]
```

You could do this with a python function.

```
def transform_features(orig_dict):
    transformed_dict = dict()
    for name, value in orig_dict.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value , str):
            name = "%s_%s" % (name,value)
            value = 1.
        transformed_dict[name] = value
    return transformed_dict
```

Example usage:

```
transform_features({'city_Dubai':1., 'temperature': 33.})
# Returns {'city_Dubai': 1.0, 'temperature': 33.0}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not low-memory alternative and not feasible for my large-scale (online) learning.

Comment: Actually, if you are using a sparse coefficient vector, the memory usage only depends on the number of features used, not the entire space. If you are using SGDClassifier / SGDRegressor, that could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported, as sklearn dev team addressed this issue in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/6173

`FeatureHasher` should properly handle string dictionary values as of version 0.18.

Keep in mind there are still differences between `FeatureHasher` and `DictVectorizer`. Namely, `DictVectorizer` still handles `None` values (although I'm curious how), while `FeatureHasher` explicitly complains about it with the same error OP experienced.

If you're still experiencing the "TypeError: a float is required" with sklearn version >= 0.18, it is probably due to this issue, and you have a `None` value.

There's no easy way to debug this, and I ended up modifying sklearn's code to catch the TypeError exception and print the last item provided.
I did that by editing the `_iteritems()` function at the top of `sklearn/feature_extraction/hashing.py`