# Using sklearn DictVectorizer in real-time systems

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

Any binary one-hot encoding is aware of only values seen in training, so features not encountered during fitting will be silently ignored.
For real time, where you have millions of records in a second, and features have very high cardinality, you need to keep your hasher/mapper updated with the data.

How can we do an incremental update to the hasher (rather calculating the entire fit() every time we incounter a new feature-value pair)? What is the suggested approach here the tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of a `sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher` is that it does not require `fit` be called. It is stateless and transforms dicts without knowing the vocabulary ahead of time.

Example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

print "Feature Hasher 1"
f = FeatureHasher()
mat = f.transform([{"A":1, "B":2}])
print "Indicies:",mat.indices
print "Values:", mat.data

print

print "Feature Hasher 2"
f = FeatureHasher()
mat = f.transform([{"B":2, "C":3}])
print "Indicies:",mat.indices
print "Values:", mat.data
```

Produces:

```
Feature Hasher 1
Indicies: [628086 849870]
Values: [-2.  1.]

Feature Hasher 2
Indicies: [196981 628086]
Values: [-3. -2.]
```

As you can see, even with a new feature hasher `"B"` consistently maps to `628086`.

To avoid hash collisions with a large number of features, you should use `FeatureHasher` with a large `n_features` value.

```
f = FeatureHasher(n_features=2**30)
```

Also, if you do re-instantiate `FeatureHasher` later, it is important to use the same n_features value for compatible feature mappings.

This does make it necessary that your model support sparse feature sets. For `SGDClassifier` this is set using the `sparsify()` method.

See: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.sparsify

Comment: I'm familiar with FeatureHasher, but wouldn't it produce (with some high probability) an effect of hash collisions ?

Comment: Omit my comment, I see now that for small numbers of features it is likely to cause hash collisions, which is not my case.  BUT, I think sklearn has a bug (see here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982717/typeerror-a-float-is-required-in-sklearn-feature-extraction-featurehasher) and here [link] (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4878)

Comment: I just answered that question. Check my answer. :-)

Comment: In terms of hash collisions, you are correct. There may be hash collisions, I know in some cases hash collisions are actually somewhat advantageous, since they help to provide a form of regularization. I heard in the case of spam detection, it is actually able to benefit from junk strings creating hash collisions.
Here is some discussion on how to avoid collisions. https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Feature-Hashing-and-Extraction

Comment: I added additional information to my answer regarding the sizing of the hash space.

Comment: Actually ignore the vowpal wabbit link. It is less useful than I remembered.